# Unable to find addon

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

New small script written and saved '.py' extension. I have installed it successfully but I'm unable to find the add-on to activate in the 'Community', 'Official' or 'Testing' category. I searched for it but I cant find. The script is running perfectly in text editor.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=True)
```

Comment: You have asked enough questions on the site now to know the minimum amount of information that is needed in a question.

Answer (score 4):

If this is your "addon":

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=True)
```

Then the reason you can not find it in the addon's list is because you have not made an addon. That is only a two line python script. Blender has no way to know that you what it to be an addon.

A blender [addon](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html) has to have `bl_info`, that is a python dictionary, and it is the data in that which blender looks for to determine if the script is an addon.

Open up the text editor in blender, then from the text editor's header click on *Templates* > *Python* > *Addon Add Object*. That is a good example of how to structure an addon, plus what blender expects to find in the `bl_info`.